# How to implement a canonicalizing mapping in Java?

Tags: java, orm, weak-references, canonicalization

I am currently rolling my own little ORM, and find myself faced with the task of creating a canonicalizing mapping in order to prevent loading the same entity from the database more than once.

My current approach is to use a `HashMap<Object, WeakReference<Object>>`. The key is the primary key of the mapped database-entity (an `ArrayList<Object>` if it is a composite key), and the values are `WeakReference<Object>`.

My main problem is how to clean the map up? When an object is not used any more, the weak reference in the map will go `null`, and I will only discover this on the next lookup (or never, if I don't look the object up again). I could make the weak references register with a `ReferenceQueue` when they get cleared, and then check that queue every time I look something up. The cleared reference would not give me any hint as to which object was cleared though, so I guess I would have to subclass `WeakReference` to store the key in the map, so I can remove it after the reference was cleared.

Is this the way to go, or is there any simpler way to implement this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend using Guava's [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html), or the [CacheBuilder](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) in r10.

They allow automatic[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069290/reliably-forcing-guava-map-eviction-to-take-place) time- and size-based eviction, as well as supporting weak keys or values. (The upcoming `CacheBuilder` promises to be specially tailored to this kind of use case.)

So you can initialize your map:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Object> cache = new MapMaker()
        .weakValues()
        .makeMap();
```

And the immediate benefit will be that when a value is garbage collected, the whole entry will be removed.  Furthermore, you can use a computing map:

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Object> cache = new MapMaker()
        .weakValues()
        .makeComputingMap(loadFunction);
```

where `loadFunction` is a `Function<Key, Object>` that loads an object from the database. The advantage of this is that the map will handle concurrent requests for a particular object, ensuring the query is only called once. Additionally, the requesting code needs only call `get()` and can always expect the object back, whether from cache or the database.

These examples are using `MapMaker` - I haven't had the pleasure to toy with `CacheBuilder` yet.

See my question [my ideal cache using guava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778743/my-ideal-cache-using-guava) for more examples. That post discusses how to combine time-based eviction with canonicalization.

Comment: I was hesitant at first to add this library, but now that I did, I wonder why I didn't do it earlier. Thanks for this great answer!